# Foldable Text in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I'm trying to add a foldable abstract box to my Quarto website. It seems like this functionality exists for [code](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html) and I'm hoping to add a button after my publications where if clicked will unfold the abstract. Is there something else this would be called? Part of my issue is I don't know the right phrases to be searching for my digging.

Here's a small demo .qmd:

```
---
title: "Research"
---

### Publications

------------------------------------------------------------------------

#### 2022

Authors. Year. ["Title".](https://stackoverflow.com/) *Journal* <br>
Authors. Year. ["Title".](https://stackoverflow.com/) *Journal* <br>

#### 2023

### Work In Progress
---
```

Comment: One easy alternative could be using [`Callout Blocks`](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/callouts.html#customizing-appearance) where block title would be "Publications"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web framework bootstrap, which Quarto uses for HTML files calls this [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/). There is a github discussion in the [quarto-dev repo](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3100). I adjusted the example provided there to provide the functionality you want.

```
---
title: "Research"
---

### Publications

------------------------------------------------------------------------

#### 2022

Authors. Year. ["Title".](https://stackoverflow.com/) *Journal* 
<a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Show Abstract
</a> <br>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
</div>

Authors. Year. ["Title".](https://stackoverflow.com/) *Journal* <br>
```

You can wrap this in a function that creates a single entry with collapsed abstract. That way you don't have to insert the HTML directly into your qmd file.

````
---
title: "Research"
---

### Publications

---

#### 2022

```{r}
#| results: asis

library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

df <- tibble(authors = words[1:3], year = 2012:2014, title = words[4:6], abstract = words[7:9])

add_lit_entry <- 
  function(data) {
    glue('<span>{data$authors}.  {data$year}. {data$title}.</span>
    <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse{data$title}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Show Abstract
</a> 
<div class="collapse" id="collapse{data$title}">
  <div class="card card-body">
    {data$abstract}
  </div>
</div><br>') |> print()
  }

df |> 
  split(1:nrow(df)) |> 
  walk(add_lit_entry)
```
````